# Excel - Need formula help for project at work

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a project at work where I am pulling a report each week from one of our systems and pasting it into a "DATA" tab in a workbook.

There are then 6 other tabs that are specified by region - "Midwest", "Northeast", etc. The report I pull does not have the region located in the data, so I've contemplated creating another tab as a sort of look-up table, but I'm not sure how to connect all of this.

Basically, when I paste the report data into the DATA tab, I need formulas on the region tabs that will determine if the State is a member of that region and populates all of the rows and columns on the corresponding tab.

I'm posting a screenshot of what the DATA tab looks like (confidential information removed) and an example of what the region tab should like. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Example of DATA tab:

[image: Example of DATA tab]

Example of what region tab should like:

[image: Example of what region tab should like]

Comment: If you're able to craft a calculated column inside the DATA tab --i.e., craft the "Region" column in the DATA sheet yourself-- then there are [a few different ways](https://www.exceldemy.com/split-excel-sheet-into-multiple-sheets-based-on-column-value/) to split the data into different tabs, depending on what's supposed to happen downstream from the region tabs.

Answer (score 2):

My curiosity got the better of me. I didn't like that the examples I linked left you without actual tables and instead just ordinary cell ranges. Depending on what you need, that's fine. But I'd want to have the data in the regional sheets be tables too. So I stubbed out an example using Power Query and self-referencing the existing workbook to query the `DATA` sheet in order to populate the regional sheets. This way, if the `InitialData` table in the `DATA` sheet changes, you can `Refresh All` and all of the regional sheets should update (in principal, you could also leave out the `DATA` sheet entirely and just hook up to the actual data source if you have permission). If you want to change included columns or do other calculations on the source data and put those into the regional sheets, you can do that too, all without fussing too much with lookups or dynamic spilling array functions.

Basically, each regional sheet has a table connected via power query to the `DATA` sheet with appropriate filters to grab only rows for the specified regions.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/asvbq9rukwna544/superuser-split-data-to-sheets.xlsx?dl=0

**Edit**: I knew there was something I was forgetting -__- Self-referencing the file is tricky. When you download the example, you'll need to go into one of the power queries, click Data Source Settings, click Change Source (you'll see the path to the workbook on my own machine, `C:\Users\Preston Maness\etcetcetc`, which obviously won't exist on your machine), and then browse to the location of the download on your own machine. Then, you can exit power query and save when it asks you to. At that point, updates to the `InitialData` table in `DATA` sheet should update the region tabs upon doing a "Refresh All".

---

### More thorough explanation with pictures is below.

1. We start with an assumption that you have a workbook with a sheet called `DATA` and a proper table in that sheet called `InitialData`. The `InitialData` table has groupings of data that you would like to split out into separate sheets for each group. In this example, we want to split the data into separate sheets based on the value in the `State` column.

[image: Step 1]

---

2. We're going to create a connection to this workbook. Go to `Data > Get Data > From File > From Excel Workbook` on the ribbon.

[image: Step 2]

---

3. Select the same workbook that you're currently in. In this example `superuser-1714937-split-table-data-to-different-sheets`.

[image: Step 3]

---

4. This will bring up an initial data selection dialogthat shows the `InitialData` table, as well as the `DATA` sheet, that are available in the workbook. Select the `InitialData` table. Observe that there is a `Load` option and a `Transform Data` option. We will need to interact with both of the areas these options lead to, and we can tackle them in either order. Me personally, I start with `Load To`, found in the drop down of `Load`.

[image: Step 4]

---

5. Clicking `Load To` will bring up an `Import Data` dialog. You want to import the data into a `Table`, and can place it in `Existing worksheet` or a `New workshoot`. For this example, I'm putting it in a new worksheet.

[image: Step 5]

---

6. The default name it gives to the new sheet is `InitialData` and the default name of the table is `InitialData_2`. Also observe that the Queries & Connections drawer is open on the right-hand side, and there is one query, also named `InitialData`.

[image: Step 6]

---

7. I like to keep my names following a consistent format. So I'll update the Table name to the first grouping I want to target, `South`, for Southern states. The sheet will be re-named from `InitialData` to `SOUTH`, the table name from `InitialData_2` to `South`, and the query from `InitialData` to `South`. You can edit the table name in the ribbon, and the sheet and query can be right-clicked and there is a rename option.

[image: Step 7]

---

8. At this point, it's time to adjust the Power Query that's pulling data from the `InitialData` table on the `DATA` sheet and pushing it to the `South` table on the `SOUTH` sheet. You can either double-click on the query in the `Queries & Connections` drawer, or right-click it and select the `Edit` option. This will bring up the Power Query Editor dialog, shown below. By default, the latest step in the `Applied Steps` section of the `Query Settings` drawer is shown (`Changed Type`). Various portions of this interface are highlighted, and I'll go over them in subsequent steps.

[image: Step 8]

---

9. Let's make some observations of this interface. First, the `Query Settings` drawer on the right shows the currently `Applied Steps`, top-to-bottom. The `Source` was the workbook file, the `Navigation` specified what in the workbook to pull (the `InitialData` table from the `DATA` sheet), and the `Changed Type` represents Power Query's guess at the column types. If you click on any of these, the main panel updates and provides additional information about the step.

---

10. **Step - Source**: The main portion of the window shows some metadata about the source. In this case, the source is a file. You can see in the formula bar that we're opening an Excel Workbook via a File at a particular path. At this point, the particular data **within** the Excel Workbook has not been selected. That's in the Navigation step.

(full formula contents for this step are below)

```
= Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Preston Maness\Documents\superuser-1714937-split-table-data-to-different-sheets.xlsx"), null, true)
```

[image: Step 10]

---

11. **Step - Navigation**: Here, we see that a particular portion of the Excel Workbook is being targeted. It's the `InitialData` table, which has a `Kind` of `Table`.

(full formula contents for this step are below)

```
= Source{[Item="InitialData",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
```

[image: Step 11]

---

12. **Step - Changed Type**: Here, we can see Power Query inferring the type of each column. This is the type, and possibly, formatting of each column that will end up in the destination table. Clicking on any of the type icons next to the column names will allow you to override the inferred type.

(full formula contents for this step are below)

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(InitialData_Table,{{"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"C", Int64.Type}, {"State", type text}})
```

[image: Step 12]

---

13. In the `Changed Type` step specifically, you can see that there are drop-downs on each of these columns. We're going to select the `State` dropdown and pick the "appropriate" values. Well, really, we're going to make a mistake so I can make a point later. But you'll see :)

[image: Step 13]

---

14. **Step - Filtered Rows**: This has created another step in the `Applied Steps` list in the `Query Settings` drawer: the `Filtered Rows` step. You can observe that we only have two rows matching now, and the formula bar shows the syntax for the filtering (which we didn't need to create ourselves).

(full formula contents for this step are below)

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([State] = "CA" or [State] = "TX"))
```

[image: Step 14]

---

15. We're ready to save! Click the `Close & Load` icon in the top-left:

[image: Step 15]

---

16. You might need to wait a few seconds, but after the refresh is complete, you'll now have just the `TX` and `CA` rows in the `South` table of the `SOUTH` sheet!

[image: Step 16]

---

17. But hold up a minute! California isn't a southern state. Oops. Time to edit the `South` query again. If you right-click+edit the query in the `Queries & Connections` drawer, you'll get the Power Query Editor dialog again. Ensure that the applied step that is selected is the `Filtered Rows` step, and update the filter.

[image: Step 17]

---

18. Hit the `Close & Load` button again, and after a few seconds, we'll see the expected result in the `South` table of the `SOUTH` sheet with just a single row.

[image: Step 18]

---

19. Awesome. Now, to show off the power of this approach, let's add another `TX` record to the `InitialData` table of the `DATA` sheet. **BE SURE TO SAVE THE WORKSHEET AFTER DOING THIS**.

[image: Step 19]

---

20. Then go back to the `SOUTH` sheet and see... hold up a second! Where's the new record? It isn't there! Keep calm though, and click the `Refresh All` button on the `Data` tab of the ribbon.

[image: Step 20]

---

21. And there it is!

[image: Step 21]

---

22. Tada! We now have regional sheets with proper tables that will update from the main `InitialData` table in the `DATA` sheet. We can then use those proper tables in subsequent analysis with structured references without worrying about having to manually adjust selection ranges for ordinary cell ranges!

---

23. **A WARNING ABOUT SHARING A WORKBOOK LIKE THIS**: If you recall in step 10 regarding the `Source` step, it takes a hard-coded reference to the path to the workbook file: `C:\Users\Preston Maness\Documents\superuser-1714937-split-table-data-to-different-sheets.xlsx`. If you want other users to be able to manipulate the data in this workbook and not see a frozen snapshot, then either the location needs to stay the same between users --via a network drive or some other shared URL-- or the receiving user needs to update the file source in one of the Power Query queries. The file source can be edited by clicking the `Data source settings` button in the Power Query Editor, clicking `Change Source` in the `Data source settings` dialog that opens, clicking `Browse` in the `Excel Workbook` dialog that opens, selecting the path of the file that the other user downloaded the file to, clicking `Ok`, then clicking `Close` in the `Data source settings` dialog, and then clicking `Close & Load` in the Power Query Editor.

[image: Step 23]

---

24. This approach is not limited to Excel Workbook files, and indeed, step 23 shows an annoyance/limitation of that approach. You can connect directly to a shared data source like a database and apply the same logic for querying it.

---

Fin.

Comment: Please also include power query code and instructions in your post. Answers should be self explaining and don't rely on external content.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Done.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365, you can use `FILTER` function and to get your data in a very easy way:

- convert your information on DATA tab to a table (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-format-tables-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664)
- create a new tab where you include state name - region mapping

  - convert also that one to a table
    [image]
- you can use this formula in regional sheets
  `=FILTER(t_data,FILTER(t_support[region],t_support[state]=t_data[state])="Midwest")`

  - you need to enter the formula in the first cell only, it'll spill automatically as necessary

[image]

Comment: I turned my data tab into a table named "t_data" and created a new tab with a table named "t_support" that has the region information, but when I go to  a region tab and input the formula I keep getting a #Value error. Any ideas?

Comment: you can evaluate your formula (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) to see intermediate results, that can help to identify the issue. If it's not enough, please post here which step of the evaluation fails. I need that to be able to help further as the formula works on my side. Also you can replace structured references to normal ones (e.g. `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4` should also work instead of `t_support[state]`). The benefit of structured references that they are updated automatically as your data grows.